# how to remove string

Tags: python, python-3.x

I got the api respones like this.

```
'(\'37.2 mi\', \'{\\n   "destination_addresses" : [ "Pimpri-Chinchwad, Maharashtra, India" ],\\n   "origin_addresses" : [ "Ranjangaon, Maharashtra, India" ],\\n   "rows" : [\\n      {\\n         "elements" : [\\n            {\\n               "distance" : {\\n                  "text" : "37.2 mi",\\n                  "value" : 59925\\n               },\\n               "duration" : {\\n                  "text" : "1 hour 37 mins",\\n                  "value" : 5814\\n               },\\n               "status" : "OK"\\n            }\\n         ]\\n      }\\n   ],\\n   "status" : "OK"\\n}\\n\')'
```

I want to remove the single quotes from this.. 
i.e 
expected output should be like this:

```
(\'37.2 mi\', \'{\\n   "destination_addresses" : [ "Pimpri-Chinchwad, Maharashtra, India" ],\\n   "origin_addresses" : [ "Ranjangaon, Maharashtra, India" ],\\n   "rows" : [\\n      {\\n         "elements" : [\\n            {\\n               "distance" : {\\n                  "text" : "37.2 mi",\\n                  "value" : 59925\\n               },\\n               "duration" : {\\n                  "text" : "1 hour 37 mins",\\n                  "value" : 5814\\n               },\\n               "status" : "OK"\\n            }\\n         ]\\n      }\\n   ],\\n   "status" : "OK"\\n}\\n\')
```

how can i do that in Python?

Comment: how did you got the response. Most likely you can fix it there.

Comment: you want to remove the first and last single quote?

Comment: but can we do it in python? is there any solution..

Comment: @PrajktaThanage , just eval the string it will return the tuple e.g `eval(resp)`

Comment: @beer44 , Yes it is  working,Thanks.

Comment: It appears you only want to remove the outer single quotes; is it possible that that is just a representation issue from printing the string, and that the actual string is not surrounded by single quotes?

Comment: If it was a string s[1:-1]  is an easy way to remove the first and last char.

Comment: @beer44 At least use `ast.literal_eval` for safer evaluation.

Comment: How are you displaying the response? Are you sure that those quotes are actually part of it?

Comment: @PrajktaThanage Dont do it even if it works it has other implications

Comment: @PrajktaThanage check my answer

Answer (score 1):

Use [ast](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html) package of python to eval the actual form of the literal you want.
Assuming your string, below could be the solution suitable for your requirement.

```
import ast
original_value = '(\'37.2 mi\', \'{\\n   "destination_addresses" : [ "Pimpri-Chinchwad, Maharashtra, India" ],\\n   "origin_addresses" : [ "Ranjangaon, Maharashtra, India" ],\\n   "rows" : [\\n      {\\n         "elements" : [\\n            {\\n               "distance" : {\\n                  "text" : "37.2 mi",\\n                  "value" : 59925\\n               },\\n               "duration" : {\\n                  "text" : "1 hour 37 mins",\\n                  "value" : 5814\\n               },\\n               "status" : "OK"\\n            }\\n         ]\\n      }\\n   ],\\n   "status" : "OK"\\n}\\n\')'
formatted_value = ast.literal_eval(original_value)
print(formatted_value)
```

This will output as -

> ('37.2 mi', '{\n   "destination_addresses" : [ "Pimpri-Chinchwad,
>   Maharashtra, India" ],\n   "origin_addresses" : [ "Ranjangaon,
>   Maharashtra, India" ],\n   "rows" : [\n      {\n         "elements" :
>   [\n            {\n               "distance" : {\n
>   "text" : "37.2 mi",\n                  "value" : 59925\n
>   },\n               "duration" : {\n                  "text" : "1 hour
>   37 mins",\n                  "value" : 5814\n               },\n
>   "status" : "OK"\n            }\n         ]\n      }\n   ],\n
>   "status" : "OK"\n}\n')

Comment: Hi Nilesh. In order to have a readable answer, please format your answer accordingly (put code brackets where the code is, reformat manually in some situations).

Comment: Thanks @Yugandhar Chaudhari @ Timbus Calin

Comment: The name `formatted_string` is misleading. Due to `literal_eval` you don't have a string anymore but a `tuple`. At least it's a good example why one should keep types out of variable names.

Answer (score 0):

If your response is stored in a string like `response= "1 response text 2"` and If you want to remove the first and last character of a string
e.g.

```
response = "1 response text 2" 
response = string[1:-1]
```

If will remove 1 and 2

**Output**

```
  response text
```

Comment: OP wants to remove quotes how this is helping?

Comment: The response must be stored in a variable
then apply the the above method.

Comment: You meant `response = response[1:-1]` I assume?

Comment: @Matthias if the da response is stored in `response` variable then Yes.